# Permutations in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, permutation, joptionpane

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Permutations {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = null;
    str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word");
    StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer(str);
    doPerm(strBuf,str.length());

}

private static void doPerm(StringBuffer str, int index){
    String[] anArrayOfStrings;  
    if(index == 0){ 
        System.out.println(str);
        }      
    else { 
        doPerm(str, index-1);
        int currPos = str.length()-index;
        for (int i = currPos+1; i < str.length(); i++) {
            swap(str,currPos, i);
            doPerm(str, index-1);
            swap(str,i, currPos);
        } 
    }       

}


private  static void swap(StringBuffer str, int pos1, int pos2){
    char t1 = str.charAt(pos1);
    str.setCharAt(pos1, str.charAt(pos2));
    str.setCharAt(pos2, t1);
} 

}
```

Using the code above I permutate a word and print them in console.

Sample
Input: bad

Output:

```
bad
bda
abd
adb
dab
dba
```

I want to show the output in JOptionPane. I tried to replace this line

```
System.out.println(str);
```

With this

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str);
```

But the all the output does not load in 1 JOptionPane. Instead it show me a JOptionPane with 'bad' and when I click OK or press Enter a JOptionPane with 'bda' will show and so on until it finish the loop. What I want is to show the 6 output in single JOptionPane.

I also try like array but almost the same output.

```
    private static void doPerm(StringBuffer str, int index){
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(index == 0){ 
        list.add(str.toString());
        }      
    else { 
        doPerm(str, index-1);
        int currPos = str.length()-index;
        for (int i = currPos+1; i < str.length(); i++) { 
            swap(str,currPos, i);
            doPerm(str, index-1);
            swap(str,i, currPos);
        } 
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list);

}
```

Comment: Don't forget, Swing is capable of rendering HTML, you could generate a HTML table of the output and pass it as the message parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:
[image]

You should proceed as follows:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Permutation {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = null;
    str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word");
    StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer(str);
    doPerm(strBuf,str.length());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,sbuf.toString());
}
static StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
private static void doPerm(StringBuffer str, int index){
    String[] anArrayOfStrings;  
    if(index == 0){ 
        //System.out.println(str);
        sbuf.append(str+"\n");
        }      
    else { 
        doPerm(str, index-1);
        int currPos = str.length()-index;
        for (int i = currPos+1; i < str.length(); i++) {
            swap(str,currPos, i);

            doPerm(str, index-1);
            swap(str,i, currPos);
        } 
    }       

}


private  static void swap(StringBuffer str, int pos1, int pos2){
    char t1 = str.charAt(pos1);
    str.setCharAt(pos1, str.charAt(pos2));
    str.setCharAt(pos2, t1);
} 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using recursion. You don't want to create a new ArrayList every time you invoke the doPerm() method. Instead you create the ArrayList outside of the method and pass the ArrayList to the method every time you invoke it. Something like:

```
String str = null;
str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word");
StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer(str);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
//doPerm(strBuf,str.length());
doPerm(list, strBuf,str.length());
System.out.println(list);
//JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list);


//private static void doPerm(StringBuffer str, int index)
private static void doPerm(List, list, StringBuffer str, int index)
{
    //ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(index == 0){ 
        list.add(str.toString());
        }      
    else { 
        //doPerm(str, index-1);
        doPerm(list, str, index-1);
        int currPos = str.length()-index;
        for (int i = currPos+1; i < str.length(); i++) { 
            swap(str,currPos, i);
            //doPerm(str, index-1);
            doPerm(list, str, index-1);
            swap(str,i, currPos);
        } 
    }
```